# How to concatenate uint to address in solidity?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, string

I would like to concatenate an Ethereum address to an uint in Solidity. How can I do that?

Comment: Define "concatenate" please.

Comment: "In formal language theory and computer programming, string concatenation is the operation of joining character strings end-to-end. For example, the concatenation of "snow" and "ball" is "snowball"."

Comment: Neither one of these is a string though!

Comment: you can concatenate anything. This is just an example. Concatenating 1 and happy gives 1happy

Comment: So your challenge in not concatenating them, but converting each one of them to a string. Thus, your question is misleading, and assuming that you've conducted some preliminary research prior to posting it, there's a good chance that you've been searching for the wrong thing. On top of that, in contrast with your claims above, there is no formal (or even ad-hoc standard) definition for *concatenation* **other than** for between a pair of strings! Your example above includes the conversion of the first operand from an integer to a string!!!

Comment: In some languages it is straight forward and dealt with as characters using built in functions. I just want to know if there is anything similar to achieve the concatenation in solidity

Comment: `In some languages it is straight forward and dealt with as characters using built in functions` - **not in Solidity**. Your primary challenge is in fact to convert each one of your arguments to a string, not to concatenate these two strings. Also, please care to mention what base you want to refer to each operand as (e.g., decimal base for the integer and hexadecimal base for the address).

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified which base you want each operand represented by (for example, decimal base for the `uint` operand and hexadecimal base for the `address` operand), so here are the likely options:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

contract MyContract {
    function concatDecDec(uint256 x, address y) external pure returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(itod(x), itod(uint256(y))));
    }

    function concatDecHex(uint256 x, address y) external pure returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(itod(x), itoh(uint256(y))));
    }

    function concatHexDec(uint256 x, address y) external pure returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(itoh(x), itod(uint256(y))));
    }

    function concatHexHex(uint256 x, address y) external pure returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(itoh(x), itoh(uint256(y))));
    }

    function itod(uint256 x) private pure returns (string memory) {
        if (x > 0) {
            string memory str;
            while (x > 0) {
                str = string(abi.encodePacked(uint8(x % 10 + 48), str));
                x /= 10;
            }
            return str;
        }
        return "0";
    }

    function itoh(uint256 x) private pure returns (string memory) {
        if (x > 0) {
            string memory str;
            while (x > 0) {
                str = string(abi.encodePacked(uint8(x % 16 + (x % 16 < 10 ? 48 : 87)), str));
                x /= 16;
            }
            return str;
        }
        return "0";
    }
}
```

Note that when executed in a transaction (i.e., from a non-constant contract function), each one of these functions may yield a relatively high gas-cost.

---

Here is a Truffle test of the contract above:

```
const MyContract = artifacts.require('MyContract');

const UINT256 = '99999999';
const ADDRESS = '0x1234567812345678123456781234567812345678';

contract('test', () => {
    it('test', async () => {
        const myContract = await MyContract.new();
        const resultDecDec = await myContract.concatDecDec(UINT256, ADDRESS);
        const resultDecHex = await myContract.concatDecHex(UINT256, ADDRESS);
        const resultHexDec = await myContract.concatHexDec(UINT256, ADDRESS);
        const resultHexHex = await myContract.concatHexHex(UINT256, ADDRESS);
        assert.equal(resultDecDec, web3.utils.toBN(UINT256).toString(10) + web3.utils.toBN(ADDRESS).toString(10));
        assert.equal(resultDecHex, web3.utils.toBN(UINT256).toString(10) + web3.utils.toBN(ADDRESS).toString(16));
        assert.equal(resultHexDec, web3.utils.toBN(UINT256).toString(16) + web3.utils.toBN(ADDRESS).toString(10));
        assert.equal(resultHexHex, web3.utils.toBN(UINT256).toString(16) + web3.utils.toBN(ADDRESS).toString(16));
    });
});
```